# Why does GNU Make re-run my shell command every time it expands this variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, variable-expansion

I use OpenSSL to generate some random data in a GNU Makefile:

```
RANDOM_DATA=$(shell /usr/bin/openssl rand -hex 32)
```

I want to be able to use this RANDOM_DATA multiple times elsewhere in the script. However, every time it's referenced, it re-runs the commands and returns new data. For example, the following lines in a recipe output different values:

```
echo ${RANDOM_DATA}
echo ${RANDOM_DATA}
echo ${RANDOM_DATA}
```

Why is this and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer minutes after asking.

According to [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors), I need to use `:=` instead of `=` to force the variable to be expanded once, at the time it's defined, rather than recursively.